# Want to find the control over which mouse is placed in wpf

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-3.0

i have a main control in wpf.
and many controls placed in main control.
when mouse moves over main control i want to find 
over which control in main control mouse is placed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want `UIElement.InputHitTest`.  It takes in a 2D `Point` (relative to the UIElement's location) and returns an `IInputElement` which `UIElement` implements.  So for example...

```
Button button = myWindow.InputHitTest(mousePosition) as Button;
if (button != null)
    // Blahblahblah
```

Answer (score 2):

i would do it using a view model. bind the model's property to the mouse over event and you will automatically have this property changed when the event occurs.